# Does MSI K9AGM4-L fit with MSI K9AGM4

Tags: motherboard

my old MSI K9AGM4 is dead and I'm wondering, if MSI K9AGM4-L is exactly the same or something that my components with still fit in.

Comment: Those two models are the same, dunno why there is no -L on motherboard.

Comment: You should add your findings as an answer below, which you can self-accept.